# Change python for loop based in a if question

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to change the iterable of a for loop based on a passed parameter, something like the following:

```
bar = kwargs.get('bar', False)
if bar:
    for i in tqdm(range(10)):
else:
    for i in range(10):
    ...
```

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: You have a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

Change the iterable conditionally, so you could do something like:

```
bar = kwargs.get('bar', False)
if bar:
    iterable = tqdm(range(10))
else:
    iterable = range(10)

for i in iterable:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the following:

```
bar = kwargs.get('bar', False)
for i in tqdm(range(10)) if bar else range(10):
    ...
```

This will set the appropriate range depending on `bar`